# Rails 3.0 One-One Association Using associated model in WHERE clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I do:

```
conditions = {:first_name => 'Chris'}
Patient.joins(:user).find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
```

It Produces (and fails because the first_name is not in the patients table)

```
SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "patients"."user_id" WHERE "patients"."first_name" = 'Chris'
```

I need to be able to query the User model's fields also and get back Patient objects. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
conditions = ['users.first_name = ?', 'Chris']
Patient.joins(:user).find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
```

Comment: I like to use that array notation as soon as the conditions start to be come more complex than attributes from just 1 table. For some extra Rails sugar you can use this format (in Rails 3): `Patient.joins(:user).where(['users.first_name = ?', 'Chris'])`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you conditions hash to:

```
conditions = {'users.first_name' => 'Chris'}
```

I've used this style in Rails 2.3, and it worked great for me.  Cheers!

Comment: When using :conditions=>conditions, do the queries get escaped?

Comment: @Chris  Yes, they do.  [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) are the relevant docs - see the "Conditions" section (it's the second or third, just a little ways down).  Cheers!